# SSD M.2 NVMe PCIe

Tags: ssd, pcie

I have a [Lenovo Thinkstation E32](https://thinkstation-specs.com/thinkstation-e32/) and I want to install an SSD to speed up my computer, but I got stuck on some specifications such as SSD M.2 and SSD M.2 NVMe. I read that NVMe is more powerful than SSD M.2.

I'm thinking I need to install an adapter to use this [NVMe PCIe M.2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07BN5FJZQ) in my computer, because I already have a PCIe Graphics Card installed. What adapter can I use that will allow the highest speed transfers that will fit in my computer?

Comment: I have edited your question to hopefully make it more clear. Please [edit] it if I have made the wrong assumptions. Do you know what PCIe slots are available on your motherboard? Do you have a budget for this adapter?

Comment: The basic thing to understand is that there are two things at play here: the physical connector and the protocol being used. M.2 is a physical connection, with a number of different "[keyings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying)". NVMe and SATA are protocols that can be used by SSDs to communicate. NVMe uses PCI-e, and therefore has higher bandwidth, though the actual speed you experience is dependent on the drive. @user9313 is correct in that the adapters he linked could allow you to utilize NVMe, but the adapter is relatively unimportant compared to the drive itself.

Comment: If you want to start a different post about the requirements you have for your drive, I'd be happy to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put (relatively) simply, an NVMe capable drive can utilize the full bandwidth of pci-e x4 while non-NVMe capable drives will run at most at SATA speeds. Linked are two adapters that should let you leverage NVMe, one from Amazon and one from Newegg.

Lycom DT-120 adapter: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MYCQP38/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_t1_gjU.AbK3KY1TA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MYCQP38)

Syba SI-PEX40110 adapter:
https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=15-124-167

Both will get the job done and are rated highly on their respective sites.

Comment: But I have a PCIe 3.0 (with a graphics card) and a PCIe 2.0 free. May I use  PCIe 2.0 to install the SSD NVMe?

Comment: PCIe 3.0 and PCIe 2.0 refer to generations of the PCIe. The generation of PCIe doesn't change accross a motherboard. What you have is an occupied PCIe 3.0 x16 slot, with x16 referring to the configuration of the slot(this contains the graphics card), and an empty PCIe 3.0 x16 slot. However this empty slot is configured as an x4 slot, which means it looks identical to the slot with your graphics card, but will only work with devices configured for an x4 slot. Both of the adapters above are designed for a slot configured for x4. This is the slot you will use.

Comment: I don't understand the x4 and x16 lanes. If I have a PCIe graphics card and a NVMe, both in the same time, the speed of NVMe can be reduced? This [SSD NVMe](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BN5FJZQ/?tag=stackoverflow17-20) read speeds up to 3,500MB/s, I will achive this speed with an x16 lane occupied by a graphics card?

Comment: I found something that explain my doubt [Everything you need to know about NVMe](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2899351/everything-you-need-to-know-about-nvme.html), I did understand the x16 and x4 lanes to traffic data, but the link explained. Thank you!